# How to prevent removing div in popover bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

By default, Popover in bootstrap 3 removes div:

```
<div style="top: 44.5px; left: 1085.5px; display: block;" class="popover fade left in"></div>
```

But, i want this:

```
display: block
```

To been replaced by:

```
display: none
```

**Without removing.**

How i can do that?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: move popover to inner div

Comment: Popover extends the tooltip plugin, which is where the `<div>` is added or detached. To change that functionality, you'd have to extend the tooltip with your own code or (not recommended) fork and modify the bootstrap source.

Comment: Ok, I resolved this problem in the other way - by cloning values from this div.